# vscode extensions search returns wrong results

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

When I go to the "extensions" tab and ask for extensions matching "ruby" the number one hit is Prettier. However Prettier doesn't support ruby and more important, if I look at all the README of the Prettier extension, the word 'ruby' does not appear anywhere!

I doubt this is a bug in vscode, there's just something going on that I don't understand. Maybe something is getting search that I am not aware of.

Comment: This isn't really an SO question; raise a bug report with VS Code's maintainers.

Comment: It really is one, because it is likely not a bug but a feature that I don't understand exactly.

Comment: What feature would let you search for things that don't mention the term you provided? FWIW when I search for "ruby" in the "Search Extensions in Marketplace" box on the extensions tab (v1.41.1 on macOS) I see what I'd expect to; a bunch of extensions that mention Ruby (Ruby, Ruby Solargraph, ruby-rubocop, ...).

Comment: I meant the search bar in the left column of the "extensions tab" in vscode itself. Yes most of them are ruby related but the surprise is to see one that as far as I can tell never mentions Ruby. Maybe there's some additional semantic information that is trying to make the search smarter. Because there are scenarios that prettier can be set up to work with Ruby but its not built in AFAIK

Comment: Prettier does support Ruby...https://github.com/prettier/plugin-ruby

Comment: I said: " Because there are scenarios that prettier can be set up to work with Ruby but its not built in AFAIK"